# Items doesn't add to my ArrayList or they don't show up

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I am new to programming and I am probably asking a stupid question but I really need help.

I am learning how collections work and I start with `ArrayList`.

I decided to make an `ArrayList` of playing cards, added methods I wanted to test in practice (show elements, show specific elements etc). And it doesn't work. When i change type from `Arraylist` to regular array (`Karta[] karty`) it works like it should so I know I am doing something wrong with collections. The problem is I don't know what because I have just started working with colections.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    static ArrayList<Karta> karty = new ArrayList<Karta>();
    static Random rand = new Random();
    static int wartosc;
    static int kolor;

    public static void utworz(){
        while(wartosc !=0){
            wartosc = rand.nextInt(13);
            kolor = rand.nextInt(3);
            Karta karta = new Karta(wartosc, kolor);
            karty.add(karty.size()-1,karta);
        }
    }

    public static void wyswietl(){
        for(int i=0; i<karty.size();i++)
            System.out.println(karty.toString());
        }

    public static int wyswietlIlosc(){
      return karty.size();
    }

    public static void wyswietlOWartosci(int w){
        for(Karta k: karty){
            if(k.wartosc == w){
                System.out.println(k.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void wyswietlOKolorze(int kl){
        for(Karta k: karty){
            if(k.kolor == kl){
                System.out.println(k.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int wybor =-1;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int wartosc;
        int kolor;
        System.out.println("Wybierz co chcesz zrobic:\n0. Zakoncz dzialanie programu\n1. Utworz nowa liste kart\n2. Wyswietl obecna liste kart\n3. Wyswietl liczbe kart w obecnej liscie\n4. Wyswietl karty z listy o podanej wartosci\n5. Wyswietl karty o podanym kolorze");
        while(wybor !=0) {
            wybor = sc.nextInt();
            switch (wybor) {
                case 1:
                    utworz();
                    System.out.println("Utworzono");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    wyswietl();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    wyswietlIlosc();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("Podaj wartosc (1 - as, 13 - krol): ");
                    wartosc = sc.nextInt();
                    wyswietlOWartosci(wartosc);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    System.out.println("Podaj kolor (0 - kier 1 - karo 2 - trefl 3 - pik): ");
                    kolor = sc.nextInt();
                    wyswietlOKolorze(kolor);
                    break;
                default:
                    utworz();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Nothing happens when I try to see elements of the `ArrayList`

Comment: You might want to get into the habit of writing "English" code. It comes in handy in situations like this. I can't easily tell what the individual methods are supposed to do, so its hard to spot the issue.

Comment: `while(wartosc !=0){` you never initialize `wartosc` to any value, so I am unsure how this is supposed to work (or how it could have worked for your array case)

Answer (score 5):

When your list is empty (so at the beginning) you are trying to add `Karta` object on `-1` index here

```
karty.add(karty.size()-1,karta);
```

which will not work. Just use

```
karty.add(karta);
```

---

Also it is good habit to use **english** names for variables/types/... - of course it won't change your application logic but will be more readable in case of sharing your code with other programmers

---

**EDIT**

As [UnholeSheep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2878796/unholysheep) stated in comment below `add` method should raise an exception when trying to add value on `<0` index but your code never reaches this line due to value of `wartosc` variable - it is being initialized with 0 and because you are not setting it to any value in case of `1` it is not initializing your array.

You need to fix this also

Comment: This is definitely an issue, but shouldn't it have thrown an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`? - according to OP the code runs but simply doesn't show anything for the `ArrayList` when printing

Comment: It was 
    karty.add(karta);
earlier but it didn;t work either
I have changed my wyswietlIlosc() to
       public static void wyswietlIlosc(){
      System.out.println(karty.size());    
and now instead of nothing it returns 0. I don't now why cards doesnt add to the ArrayList

Comment: is your `wartosc` variable different than `0`?

Answer (score 0):

You write in your class `static int wartosc;`. Static int variables which you don't initialize by yourself will have `0` value. In this situation your `public static void utworz()` method will always do nothing, because condition `while(wartosc !=0)` is met.

But it shouldn't work even with normal array, so maybe you rewrite your code and it is not working no matter with arrays or lists.

Another thing, which is mentioned in second answer `karty.add(karty.size()-1,karta);` - you should change it just to `karty.add(karta)` to avoid raising exception on empty list.